# CheckBoxNodeTree example - how to correctly implement itemlistener in CheckBoxNodeEditor?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jcheckbox

I'm using this implementation for creating my JTree: 
https://github.com/imagej/imagej/blob/ee3c360949/ui/swing/util/src/test/java/imagej/util/swing/tree/CheckBoxTreeSample.java

I have tried to search for a correct way of creating the ItemListener in the CheckBoxNodeEditor and tried some stuff myself, not working so far. I have implemented a MouseListener for the JTree and TreeSelectionListener, so do I need this itemlistener? Right now my application work without the itemlistener, but I'm afraid that I will need it later for something.

Kleopatra already stated some errors with the original code in this post. Also Kleopatra said that an actionListener could do the trick, so maybe I should check that out? :
[Multiple ITEM_STATE_CHANGED events from jcheckbox in jtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735650/multiple-item-state-changed-events-from-jcheckbox-in-jtree)

hardwired's post in this forum helps to not add more than one listener to the editor: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/10389-jcheckboxes-jtree-nodes.html

So with hardwire's approach I can decide that I only want to add one listener to the panel, but it still fires a lot of events because of the creation of a new listener every time the JTree is clicked?

Here is the original code for the CheckBoxNodeEditor (minus a method to save some space and the other classes involved). If you agree, I will remove from the listener for this method and use the two listeners(TreeSelection and MouseListener) I have created instead:

```
class CheckBoxNodeEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

  CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
  public static int clickCount = 0;

  ChangeEvent changeEvent = null;

  JTree tree;

  public CheckBoxNodeEditor(JTree tree) {
    this.tree = tree;
  }

  public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    ...
  }

  public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
      boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {

      System.out.println("getTreeCellEditorComponent method called!");

      System.out.println(String.valueOf(clickCount++));

    Component editor = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
        true, expanded, leaf, row, true);

    // editor always selected / focused
    ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
```

the next three lines i have actually removed:

```
JCheckBox item = (JCheckBox)itemEvent.getItem();
System.out.println(itemEvent.paramString());
System.out.println("item "+item.getText()+" state Changed!");
          if (stopCellEditing()) {
              fireEditingStopped();
          }
      }
    };
    if (editor instanceof JCheckBox) {
      ((JCheckBox) editor).addItemListener(itemListener);
    }

    return editor;
  }
}
```

OK, I see that the ItemListener controls the checkboxes. So each checkbox actually is assigned it's own listener. How can I add one for all the checkboxes/nodes?

Answer (score 1):

- put everything together, toString is there for override a few methods in DefaultXxxXxx for non_Vector arrays types, can be removed

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class JCheckBoxJTreeEditor {
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBox Tree");
    public JCheckBoxJTreeEditor() {        
        CheckBoxNode accessibilityOptions[] = {
            new CheckBoxNode(
            "Move system caret with focus/selection changes", false),
            new CheckBoxNode("Always expand alt text for images", true)};
        CheckBoxNode browsingOptions[] = {
            new CheckBoxNode("Notify when downloads complete", true),
            new CheckBoxNode("Disable script debugging", true),
            new CheckBoxNode("Use AutoComplete", true),
            new CheckBoxNode("Browse in a new process", false)};
        Vector accessVector = new NamedVector("Accessibility", accessibilityOptions);
        Vector browseVector = new NamedVector("Browsing", browsingOptions);
        Object rootNodes[] = {accessVector, browseVector};
        Vector rootVector = new NamedVector("Root", rootNodes);
        JTree tree = new JTree(rootVector);
        CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        tree.setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor(tree));
        tree.setEditable(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setSize(400, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JCheckBoxJTreeEditor();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CheckBoxNodeRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

    private JCheckBox leafRenderer = new JCheckBox();
    private DefaultTreeCellRenderer nonLeafRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
    private Color selectionBorderColor, selectionForeground, selectionBackground,
            textForeground, textBackground;

    protected JCheckBox getLeafRenderer() {
        return leafRenderer;
    }

    public CheckBoxNodeRenderer() {
        Font fontValue;
        fontValue = UIManager.getFont("Tree.font");
        if (fontValue != null) {
            leafRenderer.setFont(fontValue);
        }
        Boolean booleanValue = (Boolean) UIManager.get("Tree.drawsFocusBorderAroundIcon");
        leafRenderer.setFocusPainted((booleanValue != null) && (booleanValue.booleanValue()));
        selectionBorderColor = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBorderColor");
        selectionForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground");
        selectionBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground");
        textForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground");
        textBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground");
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected,
            boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

        Component returnValue;
        if (leaf) {
            String stringValue = tree.convertValueToText(value, selected, expanded,
                    leaf, row, false);
            leafRenderer.setText(stringValue);
            leafRenderer.setSelected(false);
            leafRenderer.setEnabled(tree.isEnabled());
            if (selected) {
                leafRenderer.setForeground(selectionForeground);
                leafRenderer.setBackground(selectionBackground);
            } else {
                leafRenderer.setForeground(textForeground);
                leafRenderer.setBackground(textBackground);
            }
            if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
                if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
                    CheckBoxNode node = (CheckBoxNode) userObject;
                    leafRenderer.setText(node.getText());
                    leafRenderer.setSelected(node.isSelected());
                }
            }
            returnValue = leafRenderer;
        } else {
            returnValue = nonLeafRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                    selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}

class CheckBoxNodeEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

    private CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
    private ChangeEvent changeEvent = null;
    private JTree tree;

    public CheckBoxNodeEditor(JTree tree) {
        this.tree = tree;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        JCheckBox checkbox = renderer.getLeafRenderer();
        CheckBoxNode checkBoxNode = new CheckBoxNode(checkbox.getText(), checkbox.isSelected());
        return checkBoxNode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject event) {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
            MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
            TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(mouseEvent.getX(),
                    mouseEvent.getY());
            if (path != null) {
                Object node = path.getLastPathComponent();
                if ((node != null) && (node instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node;
                    Object userObject = treeNode.getUserObject();
                    returnValue = ((treeNode.isLeaf()) && (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode));
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected,
            boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
        Component editor = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, true,
                expanded, leaf, row, true);
        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
                if (stopCellEditing()) {
                    fireEditingStopped();
                }
            }
        };
        if (editor instanceof JCheckBox) {
            ((JCheckBox) editor).addItemListener(itemListener);
        }
        return editor;
    }
}

class CheckBoxNode {

    private String text;
    private boolean selected;

    public CheckBoxNode(String text, boolean selected) {
        this.text = text;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean newValue) {
        selected = newValue;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String newValue) {
        text = newValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[" + text + "/" + selected + "]";
    }
}

class NamedVector extends Vector {

    private String name;

    public NamedVector(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public NamedVector(String name, Object elements[]) {
        this.name = name;
        for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
            add(elements[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is how I don't want it to be? The way the listener is created now I get too many events?

Comment: XxxXxxEditor is temporarilly JComponents by defualt exists only when editing started and until stopped, then there can be only one XxxXxxEditor in current time, there aren't too many events, nor from ItemListener

Comment: But after clicking three different nodes, each click will send 9 or 10 events. I don't understand how that can be correct in any way. Please elaborate! :)

Comment: this is correct, seems like as number or events too, please what do you expecting, I can't see there better and cleaner way as to use implemented methods and notifiers (in API)

Comment: I would expect that when clicking a node, 1 event would be sent. The way it's now, the first click sends 1 event. Second click sends 2 events and so on. To reproduce this behaviour, consider I have 1 root and two children. Clicking on child 1, child2, child 1, child2... reproduces what I mentioned. And this have to be because each time I click a new listener is created. As mentioned by hardwired, I can reduce this by saying that there will be only one listener for each node. Still, if i have 10 nodes, then I will have 10 listeners, but what I was thinking was only 1 listener for all the nodes