# JCheckBox in JTree does not throw its ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a `JTree`, with a `CustomTreeCellRenderer`, where I change the representation of the nodes by JCheckBoxes. Everything works until here.

Now, in my `CustomTreeCellRenderer`, when I define the `JCheckBox` that is going to be returned, I set the `ActionListener` for each one of them.

In the `ActionListener`, I only print the name of the `JCheckBox`, just to see if the event is fired or not.

My problem is the following: When I click on a checkbox to change the state, the `ActionListener` event is never fired, so the name of the `JCheckBox` clicked is never displayed. I think I am not doing anything strange here, so I am not capable to see why the `ActionListener` is not fired. It could be because the checkboxes are inside of a `JTree` and I have to do something more to make it works? I used listeners in checkboxes before, but not inside trees, and I had not to do nothing special...

Also I've seen that using `ItemListener` and `ChangeListener` instead of `ActionListener` to my checkboxes the event fires many times, and that is not the behaviour I want. I've searched about this multiple event fires when using this two listeners and I've found this:

[Multiple ITEM_STATE_CHANGED events from jcheckbox in jtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735650/multiple-item-state-changed-events-from-jcheckbox-in-jtree)

I just want to throw the event once, using the `ActionListener`, I think it is because of the `JTree`, but I can't find the reason why it is not fired.

If it is possible to do this using `ItemListener` or `ChangeListener` but throwing the event just once, it could be good for me too.

Here is the code (I tried to simplify this as much I could):

**Main class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class MainItemListener {

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTree tree = new JTree();

    //Define the root node
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root Node", true);

    //Define the child nodes and add it to the root node
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child " + i, false);
        root.add(childNode);
    }

    //Set the tree model
    DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    tree.setModel(treeModel);

    //Set my custom tree cell renderer
    tree.setCellRenderer(new CustomTreeCellRenderer());

    //Set the frame
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); // Close the application when closing the window
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent aEvent) {
            System.exit(0); //Close Application
        }
    });

    panel.add(tree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel);


}

}
```

**CustomTreeCellRenderer**:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import java.awt.*;

public class CustomTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
                                                  boolean sel, boolean exp, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, exp, leaf, row, hasFocus);

    //Convert each node to a JCheckBox and return the JCheckBox
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
    checkBox.setOpaque(true);
    checkBox.setSelected(sel);
    checkBox.setText(value.toString());

    //Set the ActionListener to each JCheckBox
    checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListenerSample());

    return checkBox;

}
}
```

**ActionListenerExample**:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ActionListenerSample implements ActionListener {

//Just print the name of the JCheckBox to see how this event is fired
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JCheckBox component = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
    System.out.println(component.getText());
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Swing: Need a good quality developed JTree with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847411/java-swing-need-a-good-quality-developed-jtree-with-checkboxes)

Comment: Do NOT create a checkbox each time in `getTreeCellRendererComponent`! Please read how renderer works. Moreover, use the example you linked yourself and add `editor` to process the clicks, as renderer only draws

Comment: thanks @XtremeBaumer. I've already checked and tried the example you are reffering to, but what I am looking for is more simple. I don't want to create a specific class to have a JCheckbox component, with all the classes it needs

Comment: thanks @igorepst! by creating the checkbox in the `getTreeCellRendererComponent` I can convert the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` to a `JCheckBox`. If I place the `ActionListener` inside each `JCheckBox`, it should be fired only when I change the state of that `JCheckBox`, doesn't it? In my original program, I define items, and types. The types are checkboxes, and items are labels that are leafs of its type. I need to throw this event when I change the state of the checkboxes (the types) so, how I should create the checkboxes for the types if it is not in the `getTreeCellRendererComponent` then? Thx

Comment: Please read the answer to the question you linked to! Especially `the number of calls to getTreeCellRendererComponent is uncontrollable`. This means you **must not** create anything in this function. It is really right. Just copy the code from the linked question and change it to your liking

Comment: Note that the used code is from [external site](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CheckBoxNodeTreeSample.htm)

Comment: @MebinJoe when you edit a question, be sure to fix all the errors in it, in this case you could also remove the "signature" noise in it as well. Just a tip :)

Comment: thanks @igorepst, now I understand what you mean with **not to create** anything there inside. About the code you're refering, maybe I'm not explaining well my problem. I tried before the example you're refering, and with that example, or I am not able how to do this, or simply not possible. What I need to do is to mix in the same tree labels and checkboxes mixing parents and leafs, and I achieved this with the cellRenderer, but doing it there I am having the problems I specified in the question. Maybe there is a way to do this with the code of the link you're refering? Thank you very much!